# Write the exact answer using base-10 logarithms.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for x.

$11^{-8x} = 18^{-x+10}$

Write the exact answer using base-10 logarithms.

Every online tutorial I've looked up does not have a step by step process explaining how they got it.

Comment: is it $
11^{-8x} = 18^{-x}+10
$  or $11^{-8x} = 18^{-x+10}$?

Comment: It is the one furthest right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$11^{-8x}=18^{-x+10}$$

Take reciprocals of both sides:
$$11^{8x}=18^{x-10}$$

Take the logarithm of both sides and use the identity $\log(a^{b})=b\log(a)$:
$$8\log(11)x=\log(18)(x-10)$$

Expand out terms of the right hand side:
$$8\log(11)x=\log(18)x-10\log(18)$$

Subtract $x\log(18)$ from both sides:
$$(8\log(11)-\log(18))x=-10\log(18)$$

Divide both sides by $8\log(11)-\log(18)$:

$$x=- \frac{10\log(18)}{8\log(11)-\log(18)}\:.$$

Comment: Why taking the reciprocal?

Comment: @egreg To get rid of the negative x.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac1{11^{8x}}=\frac{18}{18^x}\implies -8x\log11=\log18-x\log18\implies\ldots$$

Further hint: the above is true for **any** base of logarithm, not only base $\;10\;$ .